# Utilize lambda function to optimize matrix math - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance, optimization

I have a list of dataframes, each with the same shape:
`24783 x 89731`. There are 6 of them, in a `list`, `dfs`

The goal is to, for every column that is not the target column, multiply the other columns by the target. So I have a double loop like:

```
for df in dfs:
    for col in df.columns:
        if col != 'target':
            df[col] *= df['target']
        else:
            continue
```

However, that is hyper inefficient, as it is taking me hours to process this much data (1.5hrs so far).

Is there anyway I can use a `lambda` or similar express to speed this up, or increase my efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try reduce one for loop

```
for df in dfs:
    df.update(df.drop('target',axis=1).mul(df.target,axis=0))
```

Comment: Hi @Yoben_S. Though not explicitly called out in the original question, could the update function only be applied it `target` was a certain value, say `-2`?

Comment: @wundermahn yes ,it can df.update(df.drop('target',axis=1).mul(df.target,axis=0)[df.target.eq(-2)])